# How to identify PKCS of a certificate used in SSL?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, webserver

As per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS 
how to identify which pkcs is used in a certificate used in SSL?

Comment: Do you mean programmatically? If yes, in what language/framework? Otherwise it's too broad. If not, then this is a question about something else. Do you mean in a browser? -> [su]. In a file format? -> [su], [sf] or [security.se].

Comment: It's probably either PKCS#1 v1.5 or PSS that is meant, but although I'm into random numbers, I'm not into guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PKCS#7 is an answer if you are meaning signed certificates. PKCS#1 is an RSA cryptography algorithm and asymmetric padding standard.